# Instalaçao CodeBlocks CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, codeblocks

Sou iniciante em programação, só fiz uma matéria na faculdade. Gostaria de instalar o CodeBlocks no CentOS 7 (em uma maquina da faculdade) para editar um programa em C, mas estou com muita dificuldade.

Baixei o arquivo codeblocks-16.01.el6.i686.tar.xz (via Sourceforge.net na pagina do http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26) e extrai para uma pasta, depois executei rpm -a e não apareceu nada. Não posso usar o comando yum.

O que devo fazer?

Aliás, tem downloads do CodeBlocks p versões de 32 e 64 bits, como faço p saber qual devo baixar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não basta baixar e "extrair", após descompacatar voce precisa instalar, se o arquivo que vc baixou contriver os fontes, voce terá que compilar, geralmente tem um aquivo chamado README, que tem as instrucoes para isso. Se o arquivo baixado contém somente os pacotes da distribuição, então, não tem jeito, voce terá que usar o instalador da distro para isso. Baixei um arquivo cent-os do link que vc deixou e o conteúdo são pacotes `rpm`, para instala-los, faça:

```
$ rpm -i nome-do-pacote-1.2.3.rpm
```

Para ver as informações de sua distro (32 ou 64, por exemplo), faça:

```
$ uname -a
Linux pc-linux 4.4.0-79-generic #100-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 17 19:58:14 
UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```